Troubles replacing `showLoadingOverlay` in ag-grid-react v32
I am using ag-grid-react v 32 and want to replace my deprecated showLoadingOverlay with another method to show/hide the loading overlay. I've tried both ways suggested by Ag Grid (the loading prop and the setGridOption("loading", true)), however both don't work.
The loading={true} has no effect and when I try to call setGridOption("loading", true) I get setGridOption is undefined :(
How can I control the loading overlay in ag-grid-react v 32? Am I missing something?
useEffect(() => {
    if (loading) {
        setTimeout(() => gridRef.current?.api?.setGridOption("loading", true), 0);
    } else {
        if (!gridData.length) {
            setTimeout(() => gridRef.current?.api?.showNoRowsOverlay(), 0);
        } else setTimeout(() => gridRef.current?.api?.hideOverlay(), 0);
    }
}, [loading]);

return (
    <AgGridReact
        ref={gridRef}
        gridOptions={gridOptions}
        rowData={gridData}
        columnDefs={customColumnDef}
        loading={loading}
    />
);

